# Need Help the best overloaded method match for 'string.endswith(string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
dynamic counter = 1;
string FileNameWithoutExtestion = "";
FileNameWithoutExtestion = file.Split('.')[0];
string FileExtestion = file.Split('.')[1];
while (System.IO.File.Exists(Dir + file))
{
    if (true)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (FileNameWithoutExtestion.EndsWith('_'))
        {
            file = FileNameWithoutExtestion + counter.ToString() + "." + FileExtestion;
        }
        else
        {
            file = FileNameWithoutExtestion + "_" + counter.ToString() + "." + FileExtestion;
        }
    }
}
```

if (FileNameWithoutExtestion.EndsWith('_')) //the error occurred here

Whats wrong ?

Comment: side note: `if (true)` is completely *useless*, just remove it

Comment: side note: you probably want `var counter = 1`; not `dynamic counter = 1`;

Comment: @Fubo is correct see working demo [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Z76b7R) . Also why **dynamic** why not **int** ? Here you are just incrementing the variable named counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.EndsWith()` only has overloads with `string` as parameter, you insert a `char`.

Replace

```
.EndsWith('_')
```

with

```
.EndsWith("_")
```

and i would use those path-methods to parse filenames and extensions

```
string FileNameWithoutExtestion = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
string FileExtestion = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file); //.jpg
```

because `FileNameWithoutExtestion = file.Split('.')[0];` will lead to a invalid value in case of a filename like `foo.bar.jpg`

Comment: same problem after replace with .EndsWith("_")

Comment: impossible - please cross-check your code. probably you have this call on another spot

Comment: Working.. Thank You @fubo